# Quantity Input as Dropdown on Cart Page Only

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to implement two different kinds of quantity input for my WooCommerce store. On the cart page, I'm using a field with plus and minus buttons to change the value. Here's the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Product quantity inputs
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/global/quantity-input.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
?>
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="qty-minus" type="button" value=""></button>
  <input class="qty-input" type="number" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" max="<?php echo esc_attr( $max_value ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" readonly title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
  <button class="qty-plus" type="button" value=""></button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.quantity').on('click', '.qty-plus', function(e) {
            $input = $(this).prev('input.qty-input');
            var val = parseInt($input.val());
            $input.val( val+1 ).change();
        });

        $('.quantity').on('click', '.qty-minus', 
            function(e) {
            $input = $(this).next('input.qty-input');
            var val = parseInt($input.val());
            if (val > 0) {
                $input.val( val-1 ).change();
            } 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

This is working perfectly. However, the quantity field on the cart page inherits this format as well. I'd like it to be a selectable dropdown instead. I tried using this code on the cart page:

```
<?php
        $defaults = array(
    'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
    'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
    'step'        => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
);
if ( ! empty( $defaults['min_value'] ) )
    $min = $defaults['min_value'];
else $min = 1;
if ( ! empty( $defaults['max_value'] ) )
    $max = $defaults['max_value'];
else $max = 10;
if ( ! empty( $defaults['step'] ) )
    $step = $defaults['step'];
else $step = 1;
?>
<div class="quantity_select">
    <select name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" title="<?php _ex( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="qty">
    <?php
    for ( $count = $min; $count <= $max; $count = $count+$step ) {
        if ( $count == $input_value )
            $selected = ' selected';
        else $selected = '';
        echo '<option value="' . $count . '"' . $selected . '>' . $count . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
```

The dropdown displays and is selectable, but if I choose a different quantity and then click "Update Cart", the quantity stays the same. It isn't changing. How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added the `is_cart()` condition to the `quantity-input.php` template to distinguish between where to use the buttons and where to use the select. Cleaned up a few other things, and it seems to work fine for me. Granted, I am using WC2.7-beta-1, so I don't know if that is having an effect.

```
if( is_cart() ){

    $min_value = $min_value ? $min_value : 0;
    $max_value = $max_value ? $max_value : 10;


    ?>
    <div class="quantity quantity_select">
        <select name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" title="<?php _ex( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="qty">
        <?php
        for ( $count = $min_value; $count <= $max_value; $count = $count+$step ) {
            echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $count ) . '"' . selected( $count, $input_value, false ) . '>' . $count . '</option>';
        }

} else { ?>
    <div class="quantity">
      <button class="qty-minus" type="button" value="">-</button>
      <input class="qty-input" type="number" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" max="<?php echo esc_attr( $max_value ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" readonly title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
      <button class="qty-plus" type="button" value="">+</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.quantity').on('click', '.qty-plus', function(e) {
            $input = $(this).prev('input.qty-input');
            var val = parseInt($input.val());
            $input.val( val+1 ).change();
        });

        $('.quantity').on('click', '.qty-minus', 
            function(e) {
            $input = $(this).next('input.qty-input');
            var val = parseInt($input.val());
            if (val > 0) {
                $input.val( val-1 ).change();
            } 
        });
    });
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's working! Thanks a bunch. I came up with a solution too, I'm going to add it as an additional answer in case anyone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution myself. I added the following in my cart.php template where I wanted the quantity dropdown to show up:

```
<?php
        if ($_product->is_sold_individually()) {
            $product_quantity = sprintf('1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key);
        } else {
            global $product;

$defaults = array(
'input_name' => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
'max_value'  => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
'min_value'  => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
'step'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
'style'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left; margin-right:10px;', $product )
);

if (!empty($defaults['min_value']))
$min = $defaults['min_value'];
else $min = 1;

if (!empty($defaults['max_value']))
$max = $defaults['max_value'];
else $max = 20;

if (!empty($defaults['step']))
$step = $defaults['step'];
else $step = 1;

$options = '';
for($count = $min;$count <= $max;$count = $count+$step){
if($count == $cart_item['quantity'])
$selected="selected=selected";
else
$selected='';
$options .= '<option value="' . $count . '" '.$selected.'>' . $count . '</option>';
}

echo '<select name="' . esc_attr( $defaults['input_name'] ) . '" title="' . _x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) . '" class="qty">' . $options . '</select>';

}?></div>
```

It's fully functional. I now have a quantity input with plus/minus buttons on my single product page and a selectable dropdown on my cart page.